# sytstem won't wake up when opening lid

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, suspend, power-management, laptop

I have this problem. I can put my system to sleep, close the lid and it will have no problem waking up. But if I just close the lid it will not wake up after reopening the lid. The powerbutton lights up, but otherwise it won't react to anything. I have to do a hard shutdown by holding the powerbutton. After starting the system up I have no errors. Anybody knows how to change this behavior. 
 My setting are: System Settings > Power Management > Energy Saving > Button Event Handling > When laptop lid closes,  Suspend. So in my mind the settings are correct. When I close the lid it should go to bed ( put things in Ram ) and sleep. I know it is not hard to make it sleep before closing the lid, but just closing the lid should work, right? Your thoughts about this please.

I have an HP Envy C1000en ( 17 inch )
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.11.0-41-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,3 GiB
in tripleboot with Mint Uma and Windows 10.

Thanks for your time and efforts.

Comment: Have you tried by press any key or just one time press and release the power button after opening the lid?

Comment: I tried any key and pressing the powerbutton shortly, but she doesn't wake up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Setting per KDE Activity: System Settings > Power Management > Activity Settings >  choosen radio-button 'Use separate settings (advanced users only)' and selected the 'suspend' in Button Event Handling > When laptop lid closed. This worked. It is weird that you have to put 1 action ( suspend ) in two different locations though. One setting should be sufficient in my opinion. 
 Hope this helps other KDE users as well.

Comment: Hi, how to install only KDE settings?

Comment: You want to install KDE settings without the KDE Desktop environment? I'm not sure if that is possible, but open a question. Then lets see what other people say about it. I don't think that KDE settings will work in e.g. a Gnome DE.