# Laptop Freezes when in Sleep (I have to unplug the battery to get it to boot again)

Tags: 20.04, suspend, kde, laptop

I'm running an Asus ROG Zephyrus G14 GA401QE-K2168R.

RTX 3050, 16GB Ram, AMD Ryzen 5900HS

```
System info of Kubuntu:
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-37-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 16 × AMD Ryzen 9 5900HS with Radeon Graphics
Memory: 15.0 GiB of RAM
```

It has a Kubuntu 20.04 install as well as a Windows install on it. I've discovered that, when I close the lid of my laptop, it enters the sleep mode just fine. However I cannot wake it. I used the power button, all the keys on my keyboard, the trackpad, CTRL-ALT-F3. Nothing worked. The LED Indicator remained in the sleep state.

At the end of my wits, I unplugged the battery and finally, I was able to boot again.

I tried a lot of suggestions on the internet, that I was comfortable with here a list:

1. [sytstem won't wake up when opening lid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388216/sytstem-wont-wake-up-when-opening-lid)

   System-Settings>PowerManagement>ActivitySettings>Advanced > when lid closed > Sleep

   Tried that, but had to unplug the battery again. Didn't work.
2. [Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't wake up after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298198/ubuntu-20-04-doesnt-wake-up-after-suspend)

   The Service was not running on my system. I stopped there, didn't modify grub.

   Didn't work. Unplugging the battery fixed the issue.
3. [Ubuntu 18.04 Won't Wake From Sleep/Suspend/Lid Closed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176924/ubuntu-18-04-wont-wake-from-sleep-suspend-lid-closed)

   I tried to uninstall both packages but both were not installed according to apt.
4. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200125/debian-8-jessie-laptop-stops-working-after-closing-the-laptop-lid

   Did that. Didn't work again. Had to restart again.

in addition i tried:

5. Disabeling a "fast boot" option in the bios. (Didn't help)
6. Entering the console. Didn't work.

I'm now not certain where the problem lies. According to some posts, it's an issue with the kernel. Others say it's related to the graphics card. And then there is the issue that Ryzen is not that well supported in Linux I believe?

My current work around is to not use sleep anywhere. All settings do now not use sleep. This saves me from having to open up my laptop in the middle of a lecture at the uni.

As a side note. Windows manages to enter Hybernate just fine.

Another thing I tried is to close the lid when I'm not logged in after booting. I once tried it and then was able to get it to work again by hitting CTRL-ALT-F3 and then CTRL-ALT-F1. But I was not able to reproduce that. I suspect I was too fast for the system to completely enter sleep mode.

Also, the power button has an integrated finger print reader. I believe this shouldn't affect the functionality but I found it worth mentioning.

I do not intend to investigate all possible permutations of changes I mentioned above because I don't want to stress the battery connector too much.

Anyway thank you for your help.

A.S.

Answer (score 5):

I'l give you general guidelines based on my experience running Linux on various Asus laptops for lats 8 years.

First of all, every single Asus laptop with Discrete GPU I had suffered from either sleep or wakeup issue. All of which were hard to track down, but really easy to fix.

Some Asus laptops have an issue with the bios that prevents GPU (or PCIe, not sure) from waking up under certain conditions. It also affects windows, but it was harder to notice/reproduce due to the architectural differences.

Long story short:

- Check for BIOS updates.
- Figure out which device causes an issue: most likely it is a GPU, however I also had issues with WiFi module and internal devices connected to USB bus (Touchscreen). The easiest way is to blacklist all modules mentioned above, reboot, make sure they are not loaded with `lsmod` and then enable one by one with `modprobe` with sleeps/wakeups in between.
- Use latest official `nvidia` drivers instead of `nouveau`. Make sure "secure boot" is turned off in BIOS - it may prevent loading nvidia drivers.
- Check `dmesg` carefully, especially on ASPM, ACPI and Firmware warnings, it often provides a solution next to the warning. Play with `acpi_osi`, `aspm` kernel parameters.
- If using `bumblebee` - try to uninstall (just to test). It turns out that disabling Discrete GPU on various laptops (not just Asus) with `bbswitch` may disable internal fan (one of them), sometimes `bbswitch` is the cause of the wake up problem (due to ASPM/ACPI issues). Enabling Discrete GPU with `bbswitch` right before suspending may help.
- Use Discrete GPU in the Prime Profile (performance mode).
- Try to completely disable `nvidia-persistenced` - temporarily replace it with an empty shell script, because it is stubborn and loads even if service is disabled.
- Try to load or unload certain kernel modules (WiFi/Nvidia) before suspending the laptop.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, downgrading kernel to 5.4 and everything works fine, you can follow at here: [Downgrade to kernel 5.4.0 because kernel 5.8.45 doesn't like my bluetooth controller](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310622/downgrade-to-kernel-5-4-0-because-kernel-5-8-45-doesnt-like-my-bluetooth-contro)